# Visio, placing an image inside a Title Block

Tags: c#, interop, visio

I have been trying to create a Visio flowchart with a Title block in it.
That is no problem, and I can set properties of each title block shape just fine.

Then I got cockey, and wanted to put a logo from an image file in the first Title block shape.

So, I have a Shape TitleBlock, and tried to do the following:

```
Shape Img=App.ActiveWindow.Page.Import(txt); //Image gets dropped on a "random position" on the page
```

Then I want to move the image, and I have tried:

```
Img.get_CellsU("PinX").FormulaU = TitleShape.Shapes[1].get_Cells("PinX").FormulaU;
Img.get_CellsU("PinY").FormulaU = TitleShape.Shapes[1].get_Cells("PinY").FormulaU;
```

And also:

```
Img.CellsU["PinX"].FormulaU = TitleShape.Shapes[1].get_Cells("PinX").FormulaU;
Img.CellsU["PinY"].FormulaU = TitleShape.Shapes[1].get_Cells("PinY").FormulaU;
```

And the above with .Formula instead of .FormulaU

All of this amounted to absolutely nothing. It does not move the Img at all.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: "TitleShape.Shapes[1]" - this is accessing the first sub-shape in the group defined by TitleShape. Is TitleShape defined? Have you tried displaying the values from the .FormulaU? Try "TitleShape.get_Cells("PinX").FormulaU;"

Comment: Yes, TitleShape is a Title block small Shape from "title blocks.vss", and yes, I am trying to put the image inside the first sub-shape of the title block.

Comment: The formula you get from the PInX cell works from within the group. I think you need to add the image shape to the title shape group first. Also try setting the image PinX formula with a literal string to make sure that is working. Small steps.